# sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE returning false all the time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite, ios8.1

Guys I have an issue with my snippet. I must also say I'm a newbie. I'm trying to insert data in to sqlite. but I keeps failing as sqlite_step == sqlite_done returns false all the time. Am I doing something wrong here. I had done something similar before and it was working fine. following is the code

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_db) == SQLITE_OK){
    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO userInfo (name, email, username, password) VALUES (\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")", self.txtName.text, self.txtEmail.text, self.txtUsername.text, self.txtPassword.text];
    if([self validateRegistration])
    {
        const char *insert_statement = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(_db, insert_statement, -1, &statement, NULL);

        if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE){
            [self showUIAlertWithMessage:@"User added to the database" andTitle:@"Message"];
            self.txtName.text = @"";
            self.txtEmail.text = @"";
            self.txtUsername.text = @"";
            self.txtPassword.text = @"";
            self.txtConfirmPassword.text = @"";
        }else{
            [self showUIAlertWithMessage:@"Failed to add the user" andTitle:@"Error"];
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(_db);
    }
}
```

Comment: Capture return codes & log the values of "bad" ones, don't simply test them.  And capture *all* of them.  And then log the value from sqlite3_errmsg when you get a bad return code.

Comment: It's a Bad Idea to use +[NSString stringWithFormat:] to construct a SQLite statement. Best case is that you'll get mysterious failures when a user enters a double-quote character or similar. Worst case it can leave you open to SQL injection from a malicious user. You should instead use placeholders and the [`sqlite3_bind_*`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) APIs to do this safely.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had this issue because I haven't updated my create table statement according to my insert statements as I had made some changed some values that I am inserting.

Answer (score 1):

You *must* check the return value of `sqlite3_prepare_v2`.

If either `sqlite3_prepare_v2` or `sqlite3_step` fails, you must get the actual error message with [sqlite3_errmsg](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html).

Comment: Thanks @CL. I am a bit new to this! could you explain to me how I could do it please? I mean to the actual error message? and I seem to get the result code from sqlite_prepare_v2 as 1

Answer (score -1):

If you check the result of `sqlite3_prepare_v2`, it almost certainly is not `SQLITE_OK`. And if you look at `sqlite3_errmsg`, it will tell you precisely what is wrong:

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_db, insert_statement, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"insert failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_db));
```

---

Unrelated, but you should not use `stringWithFormat` to build your SQL. You should use `?` placeholders in the SQL and then manually bind the values with `sqlite3_bind_text()` (or whatever).

```
const char *insert_statement = "INSERT INTO userInfo (name, email, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_db, insert_statement, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"prepare failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_db));

if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [self.txtName.text UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 
    NSLog(@"bind 1 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_db));

if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [self.txtEmail.text UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 
    NSLog(@"bind 2 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_db));

if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [self.txtUsername.text UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 
    NSLog(@"bind 3 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_db));

if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [self.txtPassword.text UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 
    NSLog(@"bind 4 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_db));

if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
    [self showUIAlertWithMessage:@"User added to the database" andTitle:@"Message"];
    self.txtName.text = @"";
    self.txtEmail.text = @"";
    self.txtUsername.text = @"";
    self.txtPassword.text = @"";
    self.txtConfirmPassword.text = @"";
}else{
    NSLog(@"step failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_db));
    [self showUIAlertWithMessage:@"Failed to add the user" andTitle:@"Error"];
}
```

If you find this cumbersome, I'd suggest you consider [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), a SQLite wrapper, that does all of the appropriate binding of values to `?` placeholders for you.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `sqlite3_exec()` for this:

```
char *err;
int code = sqlite3_exec(_db,insert_statement,NULL,NULL,&err);
if (code != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"something went wrong: %s", err);
}
```

You then tend to use the prepare function for reading data like this:

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
int code = sqlite3_prepare_v2(_db,_query,-1,&stmt,NULL);
if (code == SQLITE_OK) {
    while (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        // Retrieve data here e.g.
        // int num = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
    }
}
```

See the documentation [here](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) for `sqlite3_exec()`

Comment: Thanks @RASS I see. But can you find anything wrong in the code i have provided? Because i had the same thing working!

Comment: I can't see anything overtly wrong with your code but I've always used `sqlite3_exec()` to insert data into a database. You should always check that `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` returns `SQLITE_OK` to make sure that your insert_statement is OK. Also you could see if `sqlite3_step()` is retuning `SQLITE_OK` rather than `SQLITE_DONE`.

Comment: Have you run the create table statement?

Comment: No, advising `sqlite3_exec` is definitely the wrong direction to go here. Not only should he be using `sqlite3_prepare_v2`, but he should retire `stringWithFormat` with (a) SQL with `?` placeholders for the values; and (b) use `sqlite3_bind_xxx()` functions to bind values to those `?` placeholders in the SQL. Using `sqlite3_exec` makes it impossible for Sr.Novato to do the right thing here.

Comment: `sqlite3_bind_xxx()` as I understand it is for when you wish to run multiple statements without having to prepare multiple times which is expensive. As Mr.Noob is just adding the one set of data, what is the problem with `sqlite3_exec()`?

Comment: No, the `sqlite3_bind_xxx()` is invaluable whenever inserting text values into databases. With `sqlite3_exec`, it would fail if the inserted value happened to have a quotation mark in it. As general counsel, you should always avoid `stringWithFormat` to build SQL as it makes you susceptible to innocent mistakes like that (as well as make your database susceptible to SQL injection attacks).

Comment: @RASS Well I feel a bit stupid right now as I haven't changed columns of my table as I had changed some of the values that I am inserting. Everything works fine. you put me the correct path to check my create table statement. Thanks again